# Google maps API v3 - pan tool is hit-or-miss

Tags: google-maps-api-3, pan

I'm having a curious problem with Google Maps API v3 that I haven't seen before...

When the user moves the cursor over the map, it will be the pan hand most of the time, but will occasionally switch to the arrow.  It most frequently occurs over a specific geographic area on the map (although it has occurred elsewhere).  When the user clicks on the map when it's in "arrow" mode, the map tiles appear as if "selected" and turn blue.  It only turns un-blue if the user clicks again while the cursor is showing the arrow over the map.

Strangely, this only happens in Firefox, Safari and Chrome.  It doesn't happen in IE9 (I haven't checked for IE8).

It also doesn't happen in the standard google maps product, at http://maps.google.com.

My page also includes other html content, specific other divs that I use in association with jQuery, etc.  In other words, it isn't just the map.  I've also got some custom CSS going, but I wouldn't image that CSS would only make a specific set of map tiles change the arrow to selectable.

Here's the html and Javascript I am using to load the map...pretty typical stuff:

```
   var myOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(38.955, -94.798),
        zoom: 13,
        minZoom:13,
        maxZoom:23,
        scaleControl:true,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
                myOptions);
```

does anybody have any thoughts/comments/suggestions?

Thanks!

Edit: here is a screenshot of the blue-behavior I am talking about:

[screenshot http://maps.lenexa.com/google_maps_blue.png](http://maps.lenexa.com/google_maps_blue.png)

Comment: The cursor doesn't change in IE9. Does it still behave like a hand as well? CSS *could* alter the behaviour of the map by putting something in front of it or changing the cursor directly. There is certainly nothing in your snippet which would do that. Might need a link, I think: I reckon it's specific to your implementation.

Comment: Pretty much garden variety map creation. I've never really used the `maxZoom` and `minZoom`, so I'm putting them on my map to tinker around. Is there a URL to your map you can provide?

Comment: I messed around with the `maxZoom` and `minZoom` on my map, but I don't see anything like you describe. I guess you might have some DOM overlap or maybe some kind of CSS name collision, but I'm sure you already thought of those possibilities. If you can provide a link, I can take a look, but otherwise I can't add anything helpful.

Comment: http://maps.lenexa.com/commdevbeta05022012/index.html

Comment: Mouse over the area in the south-central area of the map, between where it says "Falcon Valley" and "Woodland Rd."

Comment: Yes, the hand stays at the hand cursor, and it pans everywhere on the map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's one of your `<div>s` in the way of the map:

```
<div style="left: 50%; top: 50%; width: 10%; height: 10%; z-index: 4;" 
  id="activitySpinner"></div>
```

I'm not entirely sure how that is being positioned where it is (on the map), but the z-index is upsetting things. Anything above `0` puts it above the map and it gets the mouseover.